# directing one .fig file to another

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I have two different MATLAB figures stored in `.fig` files: `solve.fig` and `main.fig`.

Now I have a push button on my `main.fig`, clicking on this should open `solve.fig`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the button is `pushbutton1`, then just add the following lines to `main.m`:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
solve();
```